# How to customize WordPress admin panel menu access for specific user

Tags: wordpress

I have a contributor role which cap is below:

```
WP_Role Object
(
    [name] => contributor
    [capabilities] => Array
        (
            [edit_posts] => 1
            [read] => 1
        )

)
```

This role can see this screen on the admin panel:

[image]

Now, I want to remove all the access of these menu items except Dashboard and want to give him a custom post type access (Trainer).

**Basically, I am trying to customize the WordPress admin panel for a new user role who can see/add/edit/delete his dashboard + some custom posts.**

Could you pleae tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `remove_admin_page()`. If you need to remove a submenu, then you would use `remove_submenu_page()`. First we get the current user amd their roles.

```
function namespace_hide_menu_pages() {
    $user = get_current_user();
    $user_role = $user->roles;
    
    if ( $user && is_user_logged_in() && 'role-slug' == $user_role ) {
       remove_admin_page( 'menu_page_slug' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'namespace_hide_menu_pages' );
```